# Make window & application key then instantly return it to previous

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webview

I've been trying to make a WebKit WebView receive mouse moved & enter events when the window and application aren't key or active. I've spent weeks trying different methods and the only way I can make work is by using an NSTrackingArea to activate the application and make the window key, send the event to the WebView then switch back to the old application.

I've looked through the WebView (specifically WebHTMLView which handles the mouse events) source code and it appears that due to something to do with scroll bars it flat out won't accept mouse moved events when the window is not key. So, really, this basically seems the only way.

This works. However, there is a delay between when my application becomes active and the other application becomes active again. This creates a bad repeated flickering of the window frame as controls as it changes from the active style to inactive style.

This is from my WebView subclass:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{
    [[self mainFrame]loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"file:///..."]]];
    NSTrackingArea* trackingArea = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:[self bounds] options: (NSTrackingMouseMoved | NSTrackingActiveAlways) owner:self userInfo:nil];
    [self addTrackingArea:trackingArea];
    [[self window] makeKeyWindow];
}

-(void)mouseMoved:(NSEvent *)theEvent{
    if(![NSApp isActive]){
        NSRunningApplication *app = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] frontmostApplication];
        if (app != NSApp) {
            oldApp = app;
        }
        [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
    }

    [super mouseMoved:theEvent];

    if(oldApp){
        [oldApp activateWithOptions:NSApplicationActivateIgnoringOtherApps];
    }
}
```

Is there anything I can do to make this switch instant, not draw or, even better, another way to achieve what I want?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246153/cocoa-how-to-run-a-modal-window-while-performing-a-background-task) suggests that `[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]` `limitDateForMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode]; ` might flush the event loop of the app, updating the webView, and perhaps avoiding the need to activate the app.

Comment: So are you saying run the window as a modal? It's actually hard coded that it checks if the window is key/main, it's not just a quirk.

Comment: I'll certainly try what you've suggested. Just so you're aware, here's the section which checks if the window is key. https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/de6aa160c4855d001cc458026c3b21891f7b491b/Source/WebKit/mac/WebView/WebHTMLView.mm#L1784

Comment: Interesting.  Probably can't set that _dashboardBehavior either.  Pity. (Deleted my long comment about merely hoping it would help, not expecting it to... long since realized the event loop is happening, and you're right that they're just ignoring the events when not key.)