# Run NSAlert app-modal without blocking application

Tags: c#, multithreading, macos, user-interface, xamarin

I have an application hosting a finder extension. This extension requests data from the host application.

While running a worker thread, i need to ask the user for feedback via the NSAlert modal. Invoking the main thread and displaying the modal blocks the entire application, thus preventing the finder extension from requesting data.

My application structure is as follows:
 1 application thread
 1 thread for listening to a CFMessagePort
 1 thread for running a file watcher
 1 thread performing background work

as well as a running finder extension as client application.

Creating the worker thread

```
myWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
myWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
myWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(delegate(Object o, DoWorkEventArgs args) {
// Time consuming task
// which may require user feedback
});
```

Inside the worker, invoke an event that is later handled in the os-specific part of the application.

```
System.Threading.AutoResetEvent waitHandle = new System.Threading.AutoResetEvent(false);
controller.ConflictOccured ? .Invoke(this, new ConflictEventArgs {
 Type = ConflictType.LocalFolderDeleted, OnResolve = (userChoice) => {
   // Do something else
   waitHandle.Set();
  }
 }
});

// Wait until conflict event has been handled
waitHandle.WaitOne();
```

Handling the event, running the modal.

```
private void HandleMyConflict(object sender, ConflictEventArgs eventArgs) {
 // Invoking the UI thread
 NSApplication.SharedApplication.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
  var conflictAlert = new NSAlert() {
   AlertStyle = NSAlertStyle.Warning, MessageText = "Foo", InformativeText = "Bar",
  };
  conflictAlert.AddButton("Foo");
  conflictAlert.AddButton("Bar");

  // Run the actual modal - this blocks everything
  nint userResponse = conflictAlert.RunModal();

  // Determine the user choice

  // Resolve event by invoking callback
  eventArgs.OnResolve(choice);
 });
}
```

I would expect the modal to be blocking the main application thread since its handling the event, but not the watcher and listener thread. The latter being in an entirely different ThreadPool.

Comment: You need to pump the run loop. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246153/cocoa-how-to-run-a-modal-window-while-performing-a-background-task

Comment: Do you have a try with `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>{// Deal with something in MainThread});` ?